# Can SSO be configured via API between Salesforce and Okta?

Tags: api, single-sign-on, developer-edition, identity, okta

I would like to use Okta as an IdP.

Now, imagine I need to configure 10 Okta instances with 10 Salesforce instances.

Is there any way I can automate the process of setting up SSO via API for each of them so I don't have to setup the SSO manually every time?

Comment: SamlSsoConfig and Certificate from the Metadata API would probably allow you to create a tool that can automate the Salesforce side, but you might still need to configure Okta for each.